# PJAX and CSS Transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, pjax

I'm using the pjax jquery library to dynamically load content from a different page into the current page.  What I want to happen is

1. Add a hide class to the container to apply a transition.
2. Make the PJAX call to load the content into the container.
3. Remove the class hide class to show the new content.

Here is my code

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-pjax]', function(e){

    var $this = $(this);
    var fragment = $this.data('fragment');
    var container = $this.data('container');
    var $container = $(container);
    var event = e;

    //event.preventDefault();

    // Change active link
    $('.tabs-nav__link').removeClass('tabs-nav__link--active');
    $this.addClass('tabs-nav__link--active');


    $(document).on('pjax:beforeReplace', function(){
        $container.addClass('pjax-container--hide');    
    });

    $(document).on('pjax:complete', function(){
        $container.removeClass('pjax-container--hide');
    });



    $.pjax.click(event, {container: container, fragment: fragment, scrollTo: false});

    return false;

});
```

What is currently happening is the class is added to the container, but before the transition finishes the content is replaced and no transitions appear.

Answer (score 0):

unless you modify the `pjax` js library, its not possible to control the speed/flow.

instead you can do it this way

1. Add a hide class to the container (with no animations)
2. Make the PJAX call to load the content into the container
3. Remove the hide class and add show class which animates the container.